# SwiftUI: Text with timer style doesn't update after provided date changes

Tags: swift, timer, swiftui, combine

I'm using the new timer style (Text.DateStyle) that was introduced at WWDC 2020 in SwiftUI to display a countdown timer. This works initially. However, as soon as the date that is provided by my view model changes (e.g. click reset), the view doesn't update. The timer does indeed get the new date but it isn't displayed. You can check this by rotating the device / simulator or press+hold the reset button to see the updated timer work just fine. So it must be something related to the view lifecycle.

The code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var date: Date = Date().addingTimeInterval(1000)

    func reload() {
        date = Date().addingTimeInterval(1000)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.date, style: .timer)
            .padding()
            
            Button("Reset") {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("TEST"), object: nil)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(width: 500.0)
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.Name("TEST")), perform: { _ in
            viewModel.reload()
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Is this a know problem (and if so, is there a workaround?) or am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Seem like a bug with the button press effect. You can use `Text` and adding a tap gesture and make it a button then it will work fine.

```
struct ContentViewTimer: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.date, style: .timer)
                .padding()
            
            Text("Reset") //<-- Here
                .onTapGesture {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("TEST"), object: nil)
                }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(width: 500.0)
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.Name("TEST")), perform: { _ in
            viewModel.reload()
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `.id(UUID())` modifier to your `VStack` and it will work as expected. Making view identifiable makes it reset its state when proxy value (date in your case) changes.

Comment: Well, I would disagree because it works on macOS and when you rotate the screen or do some other view update manually (like I wrote: tap and hole the reset button) on iOS. It just seems to be missing one view refresh after the date changes.

Comment: @JanApotheker done some more research, updated my answer.